# Speed issues because of CSS & JavaScript

Tags: plugins, themes, css, javascript, errors

My website is http://julietloves.co.in/ 
we have speed issues with the website. It seems the theme we choose was too heavy, but we can not change it now. We are already live and can not go back to starting from scratch.

Your page has 28 blocking script resources and 23 blocking CSS resources. This causes a delay in rendering your page.
None of the above-the-fold content on your page could be rendered without waiting for the following resources to load. Try to defer or asynchronously load blocking resources, or inline the critical portions of those resources directly in the HTML.
You can check the speed results thru Google test, the form did not let me paste URLS
Remove render-blocking JavaScript:
Optimize CSS Delivery of the following:

Can any one help me resolve this.. it is very urgent.. we have to run ad campaigns and the site is slow, giving us big loss..

Also the Visual composer is outdated and needs me to buy the lisnce, should I do that? will it help increse the speed? IF i but new lisnce will the new version mess`up the design?

Comment: What have you done so far to achieve this?

Comment: If you look at a [detailed speed test](https://www.webpagetest.org/result/160824_EP_96a899ed6b66139dc913df640300f547/), you have a big initial delay as the server generates the page HTML. A caching plugin can generate the HTML in advance. WP Super Cache and W3 Total Cache are two popular choices for this.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many errors, image are not optimized and some links are returning 404. eg:

http://julietloves.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/55-1.png 
http://julietloves.co.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/TAG-168x42.png

I will recommend you to optimize all images using optimizilla.com and re-upload it. After that install "W3 Total Cache" it will help fix server response time issue. howlthemes.com/wordpress-caching-w3-total-cache-setup-guide/

Still there are lots of issue best solution is to change the theme.